# How to manage unsubscribe link in a newsletter with mailjet PHP API?

Tags: php, api, mailjet

I manage a mailing campaign with mailjet API.

I can create a campaign and send it with `$mj->post` to a contact list.

I've tried to add an existing template (which has unsubscribe link) to the newsletter but it's impossible.

So I don't know how to manage unsubscribe link inside the newsletter.

Comment: could you provide some code hints, so we could help you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your message, I understand you want to have the unsubscription link inserted in the body of your newsletter.

If this is the case, then you have to mention `[[UNSUB_LINK]]` in the newsletter body (see [here](https://dev.mailjet.com/guides/?php#prepare-a-newsletter) for full instructions).

When sending/testing, Mailjet system will replace the tag with the correct value, in the locale specified in the newsletter resource.

Hope it helps.

Arnaud from Mailjet.

Comment: Thanks it works and I have changed the language with : [[UNSUB_LINK_FR]]